# Find the supremum of a set using the Density of Q in R

Tags: real-analysis

W={$x\in Q| x^2\lt3$} Find the supremum if it exists.

I have that an upper bound exists and $sup(W)=3$ by $x^2\lt3$ since $-3\lt x\lt3$ implies $x\le 3$ for all $x \in W$.

For the second part of the supremum proof, I feel like this uses the density of Q in R theorem but I'm not sure exactly how. Other than just saying something like: By the Density of Q in R theorem for all $t\lt s$ there exists a rational number x such that $t\lt x\lt s$. I feel like maybe that isn't rigorous enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W=\{x\in \mathbb Q| x^2\lt3\}$

$$x^2<3\Rightarrow |x|<\sqrt3$$
Thus, $$-\sqrt3<x<\sqrt3$$
Clearly, $\sqrt3$ is an upper bound for $W$.

Suppose there was an upper bound $\alpha<\sqrt3$ for the set $W$. Then, by definition, $x\le\alpha<\sqrt3$ for all $x\in W$

By the denseness of reals, there exists $y\in\mathbb Q$ such that $\alpha<y<\sqrt3$.

But $y^2<3$ and $y\in\mathbb Q \Rightarrow y\in W$

This contradicts that $\alpha$ is the upper bound for $W$. Thus, the least upper bound of the non empty set $W$, i.e., the supremum, is $\sqrt3$. (but it is not an element of $W$).